# Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o735.fit

Tags: python, pyspark, classification, naivebayes, multiclass-classification

I tried to fit a Naive Bayes classifier in Pyspark but I'm getting the following error whenever I try to run my code:

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o735.fit.
> : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 110.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 110.0 (TID 76)  (POPRB executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function (NaiveBayes$$Lambda$3970/739115029: (structtype:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int,values:array>) => structtype:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int,values:array>)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.failedExecuteUserDefinedFunctionError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:136)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF.eval(ScalaUDF.scala:1196)
> at org.apache.spark.ml.stat.SummaryBuilderImpl$MetricsAggregate.update(Summarizer.scala:382)
> at org.apache.spark.ml.stat.SummaryBuilderImpl$MetricsAggregate.update(Summarizer.scala:345)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.aggregate.TypedImperativeAggregate.update(interfaces.scala:583)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.AggregationIterator$$anonfun$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$2(AggregationIterator.scala:197)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.AggregationIterator$$anonfun$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$2$adapted(AggregationIterator.scala:197)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.AggregationIterator.$anonfun$generateProcessRow$7(AggregationIterator.scala:214)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.AggregationIterator.$anonfun$generateProcessRow$7$adapted(AggregationIterator.scala:208)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ObjectAggregationIterator.processInputs(ObjectAggregationIterator.scala:169)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ObjectAggregationIterator.(ObjectAggregationIterator.scala:83)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ObjectHashAggregateExec.$anonfun$doExecute$1(ObjectHashAggregateExec.scala:112)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ObjectHashAggregateExec.$anonfun$doExecute$1$adapted(ObjectHashAggregateExec.scala:88)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndexInternal$2(RDD.scala:885)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndexInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:885)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
> at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
> at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
> at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
> at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Naive Bayes requires nonnegative feature values but found [9.0,3.0,10.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,3.0,0.0,3.0,1.0,0.0,-990.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0].
> at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:281)
> at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.NaiveBayes$.requireNonnegativeValues(NaiveBayes.scala:359)
> at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.NaiveBayes.$anonfun$trainDiscreteImpl$1(NaiveBayes.scala:178)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF.$anonfun$f$2(ScalaUDF.scala:210)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF.eval(ScalaUDF.scala:1192)
> ... 29 more

> Driver stacktrace:
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2454)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2403)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2402)
> at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
> at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
> at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2402)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1160)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1160)
> at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1160)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2642)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2584)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2573)
> at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
> Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function (NaiveBayes$$Lambda$3970/739115029: (structtype:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int,values:array>) => structtype:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int,values:array>)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.failedExecuteUserDefinedFunctionError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:136)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF.eval(ScalaUDF.scala:1196)
> at org.apache.spark.ml.stat.SummaryBuilderImpl$MetricsAggregate.update(Summarizer.scala:382)
> at org.apache.spark.ml.stat.SummaryBuilderImpl$MetricsAggregate.update(Summarizer.scala:345)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.aggregate.TypedImperativeAggregate.update(interfaces.scala:583)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.AggregationIterator$$anonfun$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$2(AggregationIterator.scala:197)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.AggregationIterator$$anonfun$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$2$adapted(AggregationIterator.scala:197)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.AggregationIterator.$anonfun$generateProcessRow$7(AggregationIterator.scala:214)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.AggregationIterator.$anonfun$generateProcessRow$7$adapted(AggregationIterator.scala:208)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ObjectAggregationIterator.processInputs(ObjectAggregationIterator.scala:169)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ObjectAggregationIterator.(ObjectAggregationIterator.scala:83)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ObjectHashAggregateExec.$anonfun$doExecute$1(ObjectHashAggregateExec.scala:112)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ObjectHashAggregateExec.$anonfun$doExecute$1$adapted(ObjectHashAggregateExec.scala:88)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndexInternal$2(RDD.scala:885)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndexInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:885)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
> at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
> at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
> at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
> at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Naive Bayes requires nonnegative feature values but found [9.0,3.0,10.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,3.0,0.0,3.0,1.0,0.0,-990.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0].
> at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:281)
> at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.NaiveBayes$.requireNonnegativeValues(NaiveBayes.scala:359)
> at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.NaiveBayes.$anonfun$trainDiscreteImpl$1(NaiveBayes.scala:178)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF.$anonfun$f$2(ScalaUDF.scala:210)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF.eval(ScalaUDF.scala:1192)
> ... 29 more

This is the code I am attempting to run:

```
from pyspark.ml.classification import NaiveBayes

nb = NaiveBayes(modelType="multinomial", labelCol='ProdTaken_numeric')

pipeline3 = Pipeline(stages=[featuresCreator,
                             nb])
model_nb = pipeline3.fit(df_travel_prediction_train).transform(df_travel_prediction_test)


from pyspark.ml.evaluation import MulticlassClassificationEvaluator

evaluator = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(labelCol="label", predictionCol="prediction", metricName="accuracy") 
nbaccuracy = evaluator.evaluate(model_nb) 
print("Test accuracy = " + str(nbaccuracy))
```

Any suggestions and/or help are welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide the full stack trace, not just a piece of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking thoroughly, I noticed that some values from the dataset were negative, therefore making the Naive Bayes classificator not function. As especified by the following line in the error report:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Naive Bayes requires nonnegative feature values but found [9.0,3.0,10.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,3.0,0.0,3.0,1.0,0.0,-990.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0].

I fixed this applying `abs()` to the column where the negative values were as it wasn't supposed to have any negatives in the first place.